# 2 hour delay with prestashop in Belgium due to the time change

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Here I am having the following problem on prestashop 1.7

I am in Belgium and since the time change the discount vouchers are not displayed on the front office in the customer account or the basket page.

When the customer knows the code and enters it on the basket, it works but if he does not know it, it is not displayed in his customer account.

I specify that I am on the classic theme of prestashop.

All time zones are in Europe/Brussels.

P-S: If I change the time of my discount voucher so 2 hours ahead for example at this time it is displayed.

Can you help me please ? It's very annoying for the customer not to see the new coupons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I changed the timezone of the server and the database.

on debian 10 you have to use the following command:
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris

and for the database in /etc/mysql/my.cnf
you have to add this :
default-time-zone='+02:00'

it's the same for Belgium